# Executing command ls from windows computer to linux computer

Tags: c#, linux, windows, ubuntu, directory

I have 2 computers, 1 in windows 7 and the other in ubuntu. I need to get a directory listing in the ubuntu and send that information back to the windows computer. How do I approach this?

1. What is the connection to use? Connect LAN cable directly to both computers? How would they communicate and recognize the connection?
2. What is the code needed to write on my windows form on my windows computer?
3. What are the programs needed aside from VS2010 that I'm using to program it.

In summary I need to click a button on my windows computer and target the ubuntu computer, execute "ls" and return the information back to the windows form.

Comment: How about host a FTP server in Ubuntu and use FTP commands in Windows to fetch file information? Even better, use SSH commands.

Comment: SSH is what I'm looking at now. Any guide for implementing the command on C# to execute such code? I've installed openSSH on the ubuntu computer and still trying to configure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm certain you could do something with sockets and system calls, but it would probably be easier to use the built in facilities and/or programs available for each. 
If both are on the same network, you could run an FTP or SSH server program on the Ubuntu computer and connect to it via a FTP/SSH client, like PuTTY. Sending 'ls' through PuTTY would then yield what you want it to.

[OpenSSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html)

[vsFTPd](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: Okay following the guide on OpenSSH but having trouble since I'm new to ubuntu. How does my windows computer "find" the ubuntu computer when both are on the same network(wireless)?

Comment: Okay managed to establish connection between the 2 computers. What's left is the c# code to execute the putty to connect and execute the command. Any sample code?

Comment: There really is no code, unless you want to automate the connection and 'ls' call. All you have to do is open PuTTY, select the protocol you chose (FTP/SSH), log in, and call 'ls'. If you're using SSH, you can redirect ls to a file and then mail/edit/whatever that file.

Answer (score 0):

The computers need to be connected by a network.

.. and then.. you need to know ubuntu computer IP address. Use command  ip addr ls to get it. Lets assume ubuntu has address ubuIP.

... and then.. Ubuntu computer must be "visible" from windows computer - use command line ping command to verify - ping ubuIP

... and then.. Ubuntu must run some service to be "asked" for file listing - ssh is my first choice, ftp the second one, http the third

... and then.. windows must be running respective client for ubuntu service..  putty or cygwin for ssh, curl or wget for ftp, browser or curl or wget for http.

... and then.. it is good to set up authentication...  public key authentication for ssh, username/password for ftp/http

... and then.. just use appropriate client on windowas to get the ibuntu directory listing. You can call such command line client and capture its output.

... a lot of problems may arise...  NAT or firewall problems, ssh known hosts problem....  and of course any other problem

Comment: Thanks for your time appreciate the help.. Working on getting a C# code to get this going.